# How to re-order a xml-file with xslt while keeping structure

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I know it is a basic problem but I'm very new to XSL and I don't get it to work. I have a XML-File with a given structure and I want to rearrange the XML in alphabetical order based on one node while keeping the structure. I need that XSLT-Stylesheet to reorder a XML when importing it in Adobe InDesign.

My File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Employee>
        <First_Name>Andrew</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Miller</Last_Name>
        <Salary>100000</Salary>
        <Performance>8</Performance>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <First_Name>Betsy</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Clarke</Last_Name>
        <Salary>105000</Salary>
        <Performance>10</Performance>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <First_Name>Donald</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Abernathey</Last_Name>
        <Salary>95000</Salary>
        <Performance>7</Performance>
    </Employee>
</Root>
```

I want to rearange the document in the way that it is sorted alphabetically based on the tag `<Last_name>`. My desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Employee>
        <First_Name>Donald</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Abernathey</Last_Name>
        <Salary>95000</Salary>
        <Performance>7</Performance>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <First_Name>Betsy</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Clarke</Last_Name>
        <Salary>105000</Salary>
        <Performance>10</Performance>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <First_Name>Andrew</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Miller</Last_Name>
        <Salary>100000</Salary>
        <Performance>8</Performance>
    </Employee>
</Root>
```

I found some solutions to re-arange my output but it's always in respect to output HTML and not XML.

Update: As requested here is my atempt to solve the problem. I stuck because it copyies now all in one tag `<Employee>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Root>
  <Employee>
      <xsl:for-each select="Root/Employee">
      <xsl:sort select="Last_Name"/>
        <First_Name><xsl:value-of select="First_Name"/></First_Name>
        <Last_Name><xsl:value-of select="Last_Name"/></Last_Name>
        <Salary><xsl:value-of select="Salary"/></Salary>
        <Performance><xsl:value-of select="Performance"/></Performance>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </Employee>
  </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where you process the `Employee` elements, you want to use `xsl:sort select="LastName"`. Whether you simply use `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:perform-sort`. So give it a try and tell and show us where you are stuck, it doesn't really matter whether the result is some XML or some HTML.

Comment: Unless you show us your best attempt, we can't see where you are having difficulty. We can write the code for you, but that doesn't teach you anything. When you say "I found some solutions ... that produce HTML" this suggests you're attempting to find code examples that do exactly what you want, rather than trying to learn the basic concepts that you can combine to create solutions to arbitrary problems. You probably need to do more reading.

Comment: @MichaelKay You're so right. I do have to do more reading. Do you have some good resource where you can guide me to?

Comment: Everyone's learning style differs. If I've got to learn a new language I always start by getting myself a book and skim reading it from cover to cover to discover what's there. There are plenty of good books on XSLT - including my own.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you transform XML to XML where you want to preserve some or even most of the content I would suggest to start with the identity transformation template and then add the templates that are necessary to perform the change you want to make, e.g. in your case to sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="Last_Name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjig

Answer (score 3):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
            <xsl:sort select="Last_Name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were *really* close to the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Root>
      <xsl:for-each select="Root/Employee">

      <xsl:sort select="Last_Name"/>
      <Employee>
        <First_Name><xsl:value-of select="First_Name"/></First_Name>
        <Last_Name><xsl:value-of select="Last_Name"/></Last_Name>
        <Salary><xsl:value-of select="Salary"/></Salary>
        <Performance><xsl:value-of select="Performance"/></Performance>
       </Employee>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Oh, man. Just moving that <Employee> inside the for-each solves the problem ...