# XLST to reorder/group nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using [XSLT](https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/blob/master/conf/xml-to-json.xsl) to convert XML messages to JSON format. I noticed when i have below structure the conversion drops the previous instances and retains the latest one. In below example the output has the parentrecord as SBXDOP-00P1 and childrecord as SBXDOP-00C1. Previous instances are being dropped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/furniture" Version="5.0.0">
    <ns:DivideDetails>
        <ns:ParentRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:00</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>VXXBPM-00P1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessID>ABCUOX</ns:ProcessID>
        </ns:ParentRecord>
        <ns:ChildRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:47</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>VXXBPM-00C1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessNames>AM REPORT SYNC</ns:ProcessNames>
        </ns:ChildRecord>
        <ns:ParentRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:00</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOJ-00P1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessID>ABCUOY</ns:ProcessID>
        </ns:ParentRecord>
        <ns:ChildRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:49</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOJ-00C1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessNames>PM REPORT SYNC</ns:ProcessNames>
        </ns:ChildRecord>
        <ns:ParentRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:00</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOP-00P1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessID>ABCUOZ</ns:ProcessID>
        </ns:ParentRecord>
        <ns:ChildRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:51</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOP-00C1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessNames>REPORT SYNC</ns:ProcessNames>
        </ns:ChildRecord>
    </ns:DivideDetails>
</root>
```

I am trying to reorder the data to below, all three ParentRecord and ChildRecords are retained during the conversion if the XML message is in this format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/furniture" Version="5.0.0">
    <ns:DivideDetails>
        <ns:ParentRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:00</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>VXXBPM-00P1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessID>ABCUOX</ns:ProcessID>
        </ns:ParentRecord>
        <ns:ParentRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:00</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOJ-00P1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessID>ABCUOY</ns:ProcessID>
        </ns:ParentRecord>
        <ns:ParentRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:00</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOP-00P1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessID>ABCUOZ</ns:ProcessID>
        </ns:ParentRecord>
        <ns:ChildRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:47</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>VXXBPM-00C1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessNames>AM REPORT SYNC</ns:ProcessNames>
        </ns:ChildRecord>
        <ns:ChildRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:49</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOJ-00C1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessNames>PM REPORT SYNC</ns:ProcessNames>
        </ns:ChildRecord>
        <ns:ChildRecord>
            <ns:Timestamp>2022-06-15T17:39:51</ns:Timestamp>
            <ns:ID>SBXDOP-00C1</ns:ID>
            <ns:ProcessNames>REPORT SYNC</ns:ProcessNames>
        </ns:ChildRecord>
    </ns:DivideDetails>
</root>
```

I tried following the topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305258/rearrange-xml-nodes-including-sub-nodes-by-xslt), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289398/copy-and-rearrange-xml-nodes-with-xslt), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895948/reordering-xml-elements-using-xslt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299294/how-to-re-order-a-xml-file-with-xslt-while-keeping-structure).  I could not get the desired output.

Any suggestions on how i can reorder the data, using XLST 1.0.

Comment: Can we find `IWADGV-00P1` somewhere in your sample data in the question? The text mentions it but the samples don't seem to contain it so if the textual explanation is supposed to give us an idea about the data it seems kind of confusing that it mentions values that the data doesn't contain.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry i had the examples mixed up, text has been cleaned now.

Comment: What would be the ordering or grouping criteria, `ns:ProcessNames`?

Comment: Not really since the ProcessNames can be different for all the entries. Can't we use ParentRecord to order?

Comment: If all you want is put all `ns:ParentRecord`s before all `ns:ChildRecord`s then use e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="ns:ParentRecord"/><xsl:copy-of select="ns:ChildRecord"/>` in the template matching the common parent element (e.g. `ns:DivideDetails`).

Comment: Here's the XSLT version based on the feedback, I am still not able to make it work.  
`<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/furniture" version="1.0"> <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/><xsl:template match="node() | @*"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template><xsl:template match="*[local-name()='DivideDetails']"><xsl:copy-of select="ParentRecord"/><xsl:copy-of select="ChildRecord"/> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion from the comment inside a complete stylesheet would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/furniture"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns:DivideDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ns:ParentRecord"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ns:ChildRecord"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```